# Xcode10 variables not shown when breaking

Tags: objective-c, xcode10

After updating to Xcode 10, I can no longer examine e.g. index values for dictionaries and arrays in the Variables view when using breakpoints.

Is there some environment variable I need to set to enable this? Or does anyone know the cause?

When adding a screenshot I noticed a warning msg in the debugger: 
Warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

This is likely the cause, but after googling, I still haven't found a solution.

[image: Image as requested]

Comment: did you set the breakpoint after the statement is executed?

Comment: I set the breakpoint like I've always done. That's not the issue.

Comment: what are you getting in the variable view?

Comment: All the normal stuff: VC properties like NSStrings, labels, arrays. The issue is that I can't expand arrays/dictionaries to show the values inside them like I could before.

Comment: Please add screenshot / data for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure of the exact cause, but when googling some more, I read that someone had this problem on device, but not on simulator. So I tried unpairing and restarting my device, and now it works as it should.

Thanks for helping.